# Correct way to verify address server-side with Web3

Tags: web3js, private-key, signature

I'm trying to use web3 1.0 to authenticate users on a web server. Instead of having unauthenticated users submit a username and password, I want them to send their address (public key). I'll respond with a random message for them to sign, then use `web3.eth.personal.ecRecover` (server-side) to verify the signature came from the same address before returning a cookie for the session.

Two questions:

1. Does this approach make sense? Am I reinventing the wheel?
2. Is `web3.eth.personal.[sign|ecRecover]` the pair of functions I should actually use? There are also `web3.eth.sign`, `web3.eth.accounts.sign` and `web3.eth.accounts.recover`. Looking at the web3 source code, `web3.eth.accounts.recover` might be an even better option to use on the server-side because it doesn't need to contact an ethereum node.